# NG 2 No NgModule metadata found

Tags: javascript, angular

I try to load a Angular 2 module from a library and bootstrap it using vanilla JS.
This error is returned:
No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'.

I have created a Plunker to reproduce:
https://plnkr.co/edit/le1XyV8MD8hfjaGMdRJK?p=preview

```
System.import('app/app.module.0').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); })
    .then(function(m) {
      console.log(m.AppModule);
          ng.platformBrowserDynamic.platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(m.AppModule);
    });
```

What I want to achieve:
- Create a library that exports a NgModule
- In another app, using vanilla JS I want to bootstrap this module and load it in the webapp

Do you have any idea if this is possible? And if I am doing something wrong?

Many thanks,

Pierre